# NonCancellable coroutine gets cancelled

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to experiment with non-cancellable coroutines and I wrote the following code:

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    // launch first coroutine
    coroutineScope {
        val job1 = launch {
            withContext(NonCancellable) {
                val delay = Random.nextLong(from = 500, until = 5000)
                println("Coroutine started. Waiting for ${delay}ms")
                delay(delay)
                println("Coroutine completed")
            }
        }

        delay(300) // let it print the first line
        println("Cancelling coroutine")
        job1.cancelAndJoin()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Coroutine started. Waiting for 1313ms
Cancelling coroutine
Coroutine completed
```

So far, everything works as expected. However, if I pass the `NonCancellable` context (or rather, `Job`) directly in the `launch` function, the behaviour changes and the coroutine is cancelled:

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    // launch first coroutine
    coroutineScope {
        val job1 = launch(context = NonCancellable) {
            val delay = Random.nextLong(from = 500, until = 5000)
            println("Coroutine started. Waiting for ${delay}ms")
            delay(delay)
            println("Coroutine completed")
        }

        delay(300) // let it print the first line
        println("Cancelling coroutine")
        job1.cancelAndJoin()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Coroutine started. Waiting for 4996ms
Cancelling coroutine
```

Why is the second snippet producing a different output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job you pass as an argument to a `launch` method is not the job of the launched coroutine, but its **parent job**.

In the second snippet above, `NonCancellable` is the parent job of the `job1`. As the `job1` is just a normal job, it's cancellable (but its parent isn't).

Comment: thanks for clarifying that! But then, what is the purpose of that parent job? My understanding is that `launch` only allows creating 1 coroutine, so I don't see how the "container" job could be useful. EDIT: oh maybe we could add additional children at a second point, and in that case the "container" would have some practical usefulness. Is that the intended purpose?

Comment: The parent job, in general, is used to enforce *structured concurrency* (ex. to cancel the child coroutines when their parent is cancelled). The job passed to `launch` is used to **break** implicit *structured concurrency* - you're explicitly choosing a new parent job for a coroutine, instead of using the job of the scope in which you're calling `launch`. I have, personally, never used it - it's harder to reason about and easier to introduce bugs - there are (always?) better ways of doing the same thing.